# I made an object and applied an image texture to it but it won't sohw as it did before

Tags: texturing, image, shader-nodes

So the texture worked juts fine before but now its missing the image texture and I can't tell why. I appended the object and the texture from another file I[image] worked on before. Here i made a new file. In the screenshot you can see how it looks on the cube (where it perfectly works) and how it looks on the object I want to use. Im not sure what I should tell you. Please ask if you are missing some information.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped your new object?

Comment: Jup, seems like Im missing the UV map, thanks so much :D . Is there a way to append the uv map from another blender file as well? Since I already unwrapped it and would rather not do it again.

Comment: Not sure - you _probably_ can, but I don't know how - I've never had cause to do it before.

Answer (score 0):

I made the model with ZBrush so I imported the fbx (which has the UV's) again. I also learned that usually blender also imports the uv's of models, I just somehow appended the model (out of many) which apparently hadn't the uv hence it could not append it.